# Xcode 10 error PrefixHeader.pch.gch' is not a valid precompiled PCH file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode10, prefixheader.pch

I have a project on objective-c and am trying to launch it in Xcode 10.

I get this error PrefixHeader.pch.gch 'is not a valid precompiled PCH file

In Xcode 9.4, everything worked without errors.

How I tried to solve the problem:

1. clean project
2. reinstall pods
3. create a new prefix Header - Xcode 10 again changed its extension from .pch to pch.gch

Has anyone come across this? managed to solve the problem?

Comment: try deleting your old .pch file and adding a new one.

Comment: Also, precompiled header files have the extension `.pch` not `pch.gch`.